# NASM x86-64 bit Assembly run on Replit - Number printing function not working properly

Tags: assembly, nasm

Here is the code:

```
;*******************************************************
; PROGRAM NAME - 
;
; PROGRAMMER - 
;
; COMPILE - nasm -f elf64 -F dwarf -g Lab.asm
;           ld -m elf_x86_64 -o lab Lab.o
;
; SYSTEM - Replit / Linux
;
; DATE - Started Jan. 12, 2023
;
; ISSUES - Don't use negative or decimal values when inputting numbers.
;
; DESCRIPTION - Simple mathematic algorithms including 
;               factoring, GCD, exponents, finding 
;               digits, printing digits, and counting 
;               digits.
; *******************************************************

global _start                               ;Linker instructions

section .text                               ;Main code


    pnum:                                   ;Number printing function
        POP r15                             ;Saving return adress in r15
        POP r14                             ;Saving number to be printed in r14
        PUSH r14                            ;Saving number to be printed on stack
        call cdigits                        ;Counting digits of number
        POP rbx                             ;Saving number of digits to rbx
        dec rbx                             ;Decrementing it, so it functions well with power function
        mov r8, 10                          ;Saving 10 to r8
        PUSH r8                             ;Saving 10 to stack
        PUSH rbx                            ;Saving number of digits to stack
        call pow                            ;Getting 10^number of digits, for use in printing function
        POP r8                              ;Saving that number to r8
        mov r9, 10                          ;Saving 10 in r9
        pnumwork:                           ;Recursive function for actually printing number
            mov rax, r14                    ;Saving number to print (r14) to rax
            xor rdx, rdx                    ;Making rdx 0, so division doesnt mess up
            div r8                          ;Dividing rax by r8
            mov r10, rax                    ;Saving result to r10
            imul rax, r8                    ;Multiplying result with r8, so we can subtract it from the number we're printing. EG: num is 123, r8 is 100, rax is 1, then subtracting 100 from 123, so we can recurse with 23 as num.
            sub r14, rax                    ;Subtracting multiplication result from num
            mov rax, r10                    ;Moving result back to rax
            add rax, 48                     ;Adding 48 to rax for unicode, otherwise, printing, for example, 1, wouldent print one but unicode char with code 1
            mov [temp_var], rax             ;Save result of division to variable, for printing
            mov rax, 1                      ;System write 
            mov rdi, 1                      ;Stdout 
            mov rsi, temp_var               ;Message to be sent
            mov rdx, temp_var_len           ;Message length
            syscall                         ;Printing message
            xor rdx, rdx                    ;Making rdx 0
            mov rax, r8                     ;Making rax r8
            div r9                          ;Dividing r8 by 10
            mov r8, rax                     ;Making r8 the division result, so when recursing we keep up with each digit in the number to print
            mov rax, r14                    ;Moving number to print to rax
            cmp rax, 0                      ;Comparing it with zero
            jnz pnumwork                    ;If it is zero, stop recursing, else, recurse
        PUSH r15                            ;Pushing return address to top of stack
        ret                                 ;Return to location the function was called from

    cdigits:                                ;Digit counting function
        POP rbx                             ;Saving return adress to rbx
        POP rax                             ;Getting number to count digits of, saving to rax
        mov r8, 10                          ;Making r8 10
        mov r9, 0                           ;Making r9 0
        cdigitswork:                        ;Recursing function
            xor rdx, rdx                    ;Making rdx 0
            div r8                          ;Dividing number to count digits of by 10
            inc r9                          ;Incrementing r9 (number of digits counter variable)
            cmp rax, 0                      ;Comparing division result with 0
            jnz cdigitswork                 ;If rax is 0, exit recursive function, else, recurse.
        PUSH r9                             ;Push result number to stack
        PUSH rbx                            ;Push return adress to stack
        ret                                 ;Return to location the function was called from

    pow:                                    ;Function to get a number to the power of another
        POP r8                              ;Save return adress to r8
        POP r9                              ;Save exponent to r9
        dec r9                              ;Decrement exponent, for compatibility with recursive function
        POP r10                             ;Save base to r10
        mov r11, r10                        ;Make r11 equal to r10
        mov rcx, r9                         ;Move rcx to r9 (most likely this is vestigial, im not messing with it just in case.)
        powwork:                            ;Recursive function
            imul r10, r11                   ;Multiply base by copy of itself
            dec r9                          ;Decrement loop counter
            cmp r9, 0                       ;Compare loop counter with zero
            jne powwork                     ;If so, exit recursive function, else, recurse
        PUSH r10                            ;Push result to stack
        PUSH r8                             ;Push return adress to stack
        ret                                 ;Return to location the function was called from
            

    factors:                                ;Get factors of number (unfinished)
        POP r8                              ;Save return adress to r8
        POP r9                              ;Save number to r9
        PUSH r8                             ;Push return adress back onto stack
        mov rax, 1                          ;Print factors message one
        mov rdi, 1                          ;           |
        mov rsi, factors_msg_1              ;           |
        mov rdx, factors_msg_1_len          ;           |
        syscall                             ;End print factors message one
        PUSH r9                             ;Save number on stack
        PUSH r9                             ;Push number (for printing) on to stack
        call pnum                           ;Print number (issue here)
        mov rax, 1                          ;Print factors message two
        mov rdi, 1                          ;           |
        mov rsi, factors_msg_2              ;           |
        mov rdx, factors_msg_2_len          ;           |
        syscall                             ;End print factors message two
        POP r9                              ;Save number to r9
        ret                                 ;Return to location the function was called from


    _start:                                 ;Linker instruction, code starts execution here
        mov rax, 50                         ;Save 50 to rax
        PUSH rax                            ;Push rax onto stack, for factoring
        call factors                        ;Factor number


;********************************************************
;                       System exit
;********************************************************

    mov    eax, 60                          ;System exit code
    mov    rdi, 0                           ;Success code
    syscall                                 ;Exit program


section .data                               ;Data for use in program

temp_var: times 256 db 0                    ;Save number printing variable with a buffer
temp_var_len: equ $-temp_var                ;Save the length of temp_var
factors_msg_1: db 0x0A, 'The factors of '
factors_msg_1_len: equ $-factors_msg_1
factors_msg_2: db ' are', 0x3A, 0x0A
factors_msg_2_len: equ $-factors_msg_2
factors_comma: db ','
factors_comma_len: equ $-factors_comma
factors_period: db ','
factors_period_len: equ $-factors_period
```

When this program is run, It prints the message: `The factors of `, then the caret stops in place. It makes me think that it's in the number printing function, most likely caught on a loop somewhere. But what I'm wondering is where the issue is, since I've done stand alone tests of the print function. If anyone has any idea of the issue, it would be nice to get a different perspective than my own on it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
;*******************************************************
; PROGRAM NAME - Lab 0010 - Simple Algorithms
;
; PROGRAMMER - David Weir
;
; COMPILE - nasm -f elf64 -F dwarf -g Lab.asm
;           ld -m elf_x86_64 -o lab Lab.o
;
; SYSTEM - Replit
;
; DATE - Started Jan. 12, 2023
;
; ISSUES - Don't use negative or decimal values when inputting numbers.
;
; DESCRIPTION - Simple mathematic algorithms including 
;               factoring, GCD, exponents, finding 
;               digits, printing digits, and counting 
;               digits.
; *******************************************************

global _start                               ;Linker instructions

section .text                               ;Main code


    pnum:                                   ;Number printing function
        POP r15                             ;Saving return adress in r15
        POP r14                             ;Saving number to be printed in r14
        PUSH r14                            ;Saving number to be printed on stack
        call cdigits                        ;Counting digits of number
        POP rbx                             ;Saving number of digits to rbx
        mov r8, 10                          ;Saving 10 to r8
        PUSH r8                             ;Saving 10 to stack
        PUSH rbx                            ;Saving number of digits to stack
        call pow                            ;Getting 10^number of digits, for use in printing function
        POP r8                              ;Saving that number to r8
        mov r9, 10                          ;Saving 10 in r9
        pnumwork:                           ;Recursive function for actually printing number
            mov rax, r14                    ;Saving number to print (r14) to rax
            xor rdx, rdx                    ;Making rdx 0, so division doesnt mess up
            div r8                          ;Dividing rax by r8
            mov r10, rax                    ;Saving result to r10
            imul rax, r8                    ;Multiplying result with r8, so we can subtract it from the number we're printing. EG: num is 123, r8 is 100, rax is 1, then subtracting 100 from 123, so we can recurse with 23 as num.
            sub r14, rax                    ;Subtracting multiplication result from num
            mov rax, r10                    ;Moving result back to rax
            add rax, 48                     ;Adding 48 to rax for unicode, otherwise, printing, for example, 1, wouldent print one but unicode char with code 1
            mov [temp_var], rax             ;Save result of division to variable, for printing
            mov rax, 1                      ;System write 
            mov rdi, 1                      ;Stdout 
            mov rsi, temp_var               ;Message to be sent
            mov rdx, temp_var_len           ;Message length
            syscall                         ;Printing message
            xor rdx, rdx                    ;Making rdx 0
            mov rax, r8                     ;Making rax r8
            div r9                          ;Dividing r8 by 10
            mov r8, rax                     ;Making r8 the division result, so when recursing we keep up with each digit in the number to print
            mov rax, r14                    ;Moving number to print to rax
            cmp r8, 0                       ;Comparing it with zero
            jnz pnumwork                    ;If it is zero, stop recursing, else, recurse
        PUSH r15                            ;Pushing return address to top of stack
        ret                                 ;Return to location the function was called from

    cdigits:                                ;Digit counting function
        POP rbx                             ;Saving return adress to rbx
        POP rax                             ;Getting number to count digits of, saving to rax
        mov r8, 10                          ;Making r8 10
        mov r9, 0                           ;Making r9 0
        cdigitswork:                        ;Recursing function
            xor rdx, rdx                    ;Making rdx 0
            div r8                          ;Dividing number to count digits of by 10
            inc r9                          ;Incrementing r9 (number of digits counter variable)
            cmp rax, 0                      ;Comparing division result with 0
            jnz cdigitswork                 ;If rax is 0, exit recursive function, else, recurse.
        PUSH r9                             ;Push result number to stack
        PUSH rbx                            ;Push return adress to stack
        ret                                 ;Return to location the function was called from

    pow:                                    ;Function to get a number to the power of another
        POP r8                              ;Save return adress to r8
        POP r9                              ;Save exponent to r9
        POP r10                             ;Save base to r10
        mov r11, r10                        ;Make r11 equal to r10
        mov rax, r9                         ;Make rax equal r9 for comparison below
        dec r9
        jnz powwork                         ;If number isn't zero, go to recursive function
        jmp fi                              ;Jump to exit of function if number is zero
        powwork:                            ;Recursive function
            imul r10, r11                   ;Multiply base by copy of itself
            dec r9                          ;Decrement loop counter
            mov rax, r9                     ;Make rax equal r9 for comparison below
            jnz powwork                     ;If negative, exit recursive function, else, recurse
        fi:
        xor rdx, rdx                        ;Make rdx zero
        mov rax, r10                        ;Make rax equal to result
        div r11                             ;Divide by base
        mov r10, rax                        ;Move result back to r10
        PUSH r10                            ;Push result to stack
        PUSH r8                             ;Push return adress to stack
        ret                                 ;Return to location the function was called from
            

    factors:                                ;Get factors of number (unfinished)
        POP r8                              ;Save return adress to r8
        POP r9                              ;Save number to r9
        PUSH r8                             ;Push return adress back onto stack
        mov rax, 1                          ;Print factors message one
        mov rdi, 1                          ;           |
        mov rsi, factors_msg_1              ;           |
        mov rdx, factors_msg_1_len          ;           |
        syscall                             ;End print factors message one
        PUSH r9                             ;Save number on stack
        PUSH r9                             ;Push number (for printing) on to stack
        call pnum                           ;Print number (issue here)
        mov rax, 1                          ;Print factors message two
        mov rdi, 1                          ;           |
        mov rsi, factors_msg_2              ;           |
        mov rdx, factors_msg_2_len          ;           |
        syscall                             ;End print factors message two
        POP r9                              ;Save number to r9
        ret                                 ;Return to location the function was called from


    _start:                                 ;Linker instruction, code starts execution here
        mov rax, 5                          ;Save 50 to rax
        PUSH rax                            ;Push rax onto stack, for factoring
        call factors                        ;Factor number


;********************************************************
;                       System exit
;********************************************************

    mov    eax, 60                          ;System exit code
    mov    rdi, 0                           ;Success code
    syscall                                 ;Exit program


section .data                               ;Data for use in program

temp_var: times 256 db 0                    ;Save number printing variable with a buffer
temp_var_len: equ $-temp_var                ;Save the length of temp_var
factors_msg_1: db 0x0A, 'The factors of '
factors_msg_1_len: equ $-factors_msg_1
factors_msg_2: db ' are', 0x3A, 0x0A
factors_msg_2_len: equ $-factors_msg_2
factors_comma: db ','
factors_comma_len: equ $-factors_comma
factors_period: db ','
factors_period_len: equ $-factors_period
```

Comment: Please explain what changes were needed to solve the issue. People don't generally like to play the game "find the 10 differences".